# Why is bundler unable to reach http://rubygems.org?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

Bundle install was working perfectly yesterday but now it's returning this output in the CL:

```
   ~/dev/rails/sample_app$ bundle install
   Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.
   Error Bundler::HTTPError during request to dependency API
   Fetching full source index from https://rubygems.org/
   Could not reach https://rubygems.org/
```

the only change I made to the gem file was to add the gem for factory girl (1.4.0) in the test group.

I'm not working behind any proxies and I'm fully connected to the internet as well. Can't seem to find anything like this on google either. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Seems like a network issue, can you `ping https://rubygems.org/`?

Comment: the response is ping: uknown host https://rubygems.org/...

Comment: @tjkoding Then something is broken; I can ping it just fine. But that's why you can't reach it.

Comment: The website resolves fine in the browser...not sure why it wouldn't for the Bundle. Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks for all the help folks.

Comment: `ping http://anything.at.all`?  Sorry...`ping` uses IP addresses, not URLs.

Comment: Huh that's coming back with an unknown host.

Comment: This is not network technical support. Please refactor your question into a resolver-related question on superuser.com or serverfault.com, if a suitable answer doesn't already exist there.

Comment: FYI it's `ping rubygems.org`, no http. Ping is it's own thing.

Comment: Check http://status.rubygems.org. I had this error and it was because Dependency API was down.

Comment: @GuiGS's comment should be the answer, there's no way to `bundle update right` now

Comment: This is concerning. One site goes down, or even a service, like the dependency API, and rubygems source, which is used by many many applications, won't work. Can't pull metadata, can't update with bundler..I mean..wow. How can we put all that responsibility on a single service?

Comment: For me, `http://rubygems.org` wasn't working, but it started when I changed it to `http://www.rubygems.org`!

Comment: Restart your terminal, will do the job
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10880857/why-is-bundler-unable-to-reach-http-rubygems-org

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not a gem or ruby issue, this is a resolver issue, as you could tell from your `uknown host rubygems.org` response.

If your browser is resolving, try sites like:

- http://isitup.org/rubygems.org
- http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/rubygems.org

to validate that your problem is localized.

Comment: Note that the response includes a link.  That's Markdown's doing whenever a URL is posted.  He was just given crappy instructions on what/how to ping.

Comment: @cHao Ok the problem is definitely localized then as it states that ruby gems is up and the it's down just for me. How should I move forward from here?

Comment: Sorry to say it, but "have you tried turning it off and on again?". Seriously.

Comment: And by "it", I mean the computer you're running bundler on.

Answer (score 8):

Is it working when you remove the new line ?

Maybe, you should switch the Gemfile to use `http` instead of `https`

Comment: I've tried removing the new line but that hasn't affected anything, and using http doesn't seem to have any effect either...

Comment: I can also ping other websites by their domain names so not a DNS issue either

Comment: I had the same problem. It was resolved by using `http://rubygems.org/` instead of `https://rubygems.org/` in my `Gemfile`.

Comment: Running 'bundle' on a new terminal session resolved this issue for me

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like you may be behind a proxy server.

Try (unix/os x)

```
$ export http_proxy=http://username:password@your-proxy-site.com:[your_proxy_port]
```

You may be able to get the info out of your web browser if you aren't aware of the values on your own.

On windows, you can do this by going to Environment variables and adding a new one called http_proxy with the values above.

Comment: The big problem is, the `http_proxy` variable is not persistent during the Capistrano Deployment session.